# configure URL access control for domains using .htaccess or other methods

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am having a scenario as following:

For example,I have a website http://www.MyWebSite.com, and I have setup another subdomain http://image.MyWebSite.com. In Apache virtual host setting, they are using the same folder (e.g. /home/mywebsite/). (these two domains have different bandwidth setup using mod_cband).

I have a subfolders "/home/mywebsite/files/images", I want to make it only accessible from the subdomain "http://image.MyWebSite.com/files/images/*..." but NOT "http://www.MyWebSite.com/files/images/*..."

How shall I configure this with .htaccess file or any other equivalent methods?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they use the same directory the only way you can do this is via a RewriteRule specifically for the main domain. Put this in a file called `.htaccess` in the root of your website.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
# If the request is for www.example.com ...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
# ... and the URL starts with files/images, deny access ([F] = Forbidden)
RewriteRule ^files/images - [F]
```

Comment: thanks, if I want to put .htaccess in the folder of "files/images", how shall I configure it please?

Comment: Replace `^files/images` with `.?` -- meaning 'any request'

Comment: thanks so much! Just one more thing, if I want to have "www.example.com" and "example.com" both denied, how shall I do it?

Comment: Change `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]` to `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]`. That will match both example.com and www.example.com